# How to aggregate the last row of multiple dataframes into one aggregate dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have several data frames, for example:

Dataframe 1

```
   A  B  
0  x  9  
1  x  8  
2  x  7  
3  y  6
```

Dataframe 2

```
    A  B  
0  a  1  
1  b  2  
2  c  3  
3  d  4
```

and I want to create an aggregate dataframe:

Dataframe Aggregate

```
            A  B  
Dataframe1  y  6  
Dataframe2  d  4
```

I've been trying:

```
for n in range(1, len(df_list), 1):  
    df_aggregate.loc[n:] = df_temp.loc[-1:]
```

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `iloc` and `pd.concat` for this:

```
df_all = pd.concat([d.iloc[-1:] for d in df_list], ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way:

```
df = df1.tail(1).append(df2.tail(1))
print(df)

   B
A
y  6
d  4
```